# purpose of auto increment flag in hazelcast config

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am not completely certain about the purpose for the auto-increment flag in the hazelcast xml config file.  When I have that turned off, I see multiple exceptions in my server instance complaining about port not being open (already in use) for port 5701 (since hazelcast is no longer moving over to port 5702 etc).  Why does Hazelcast need this property when I am using tcp enabled server setup?

I see the following in my log statements after running the server and it seems to be be listening on port 5701 (default in config):

```
Members [1] {
        Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 this
}

2014-09-05 05:46:00,407 INFO c.h.c.LifecycleService [main] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Address[127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
2014-09-05 05:46:00,414 INFO c.a.c.n.SendServerEmail [main] hazelcast server email notification for server 192.168.110.154 WildMetrix Hazelcast server launched at 192.168.110.154
2014-09-05 05:46:01,336 INFO c.h.p.InternalPartitionService [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-1] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Initializing cluster partition table first arrangement...
2014-09-05 05:46:01,521 INFO c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [main] null [dev] [3.2.4] Interfaces is disabled, trying to pick one address from TCP-IP config addresses: [127.0.0.1]
2014-09-05 05:46:01,522 INFO c.h.i.DefaultAddressPicker [main] null [dev] [3.2.4] Picked Address[127.0.0.1]:5702, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5702], bind any local is true
2014-09-05 05:46:01,602 INFO c.h.system [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Hazelcast 3.2.4 (20140721) starting at Address[127.0.0.1]:5702
2014-09-05 05:46:01,602 INFO c.h.system [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Hazelcast.com
2014-09-05 05:46:01,604 INFO c.h.i.Node [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Creating TcpIpJoiner
2014-09-05 05:46:01,606 INFO c.h.c.LifecycleService [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Address[127.0.0.1]:5702 is STARTING
2014-09-05 05:46:01,619 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5703
2014-09-05 05:46:01,620 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5701
2014-09-05 05:46:01,620 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
2014-09-05 05:46:01,621 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Could not connect to: /127.0.0.1:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /127.0.0.1:5703]
2014-09-05 05:46:01,621 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5701, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
2014-09-05 05:46:01,628 INFO c.h.n.SocketAcceptor [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-Acceptor] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] Accepting socket connection from /127.0.0.1:46001
2014-09-05 05:46:01,639 INFO c.h.n.TcpIpConnectionManager [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] 46001 accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:5701
2014-09-05 05:46:01,639 INFO c.h.n.TcpIpConnectionManager [hz._hzInstance_1_dev.IO.thread-Acceptor] [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.2.4] 5701 accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:46001
2014-09-05 05:46:38,637 WARN c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Couldn't join to the master : Address[127.0.0.1]:5701
2014-09-05 05:46:38,638 WARN c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Failed to connect, node joined= false, allConnected= false to all other members after 0 seconds.
2014-09-05 05:46:38,638 WARN c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Rebooting after 10 seconds.
2014-09-05 05:46:48,639 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5703
2014-09-05 05:46:48,639 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-1] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
2014-09-05 05:46:48,640 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-1] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Could not connect to: /127.0.0.1:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /127.0.0.1:5703]
2014-09-05 05:46:48,640 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5701
2014-09-05 05:47:14,648 WARN c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Failed to connect, node joined= false, allConnected= false to all other members after 0 seconds.
2014-09-05 05:47:14,648 WARN c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Rebooting after 10 seconds.
2014-09-05 05:47:24,649 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5703
2014-09-05 05:47:24,649 INFO c.h.c.TcpIpJoiner [main] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to possible member: Address[127.0.0.1]:5701
2014-09-05 05:47:24,649 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Connecting to /127.0.0.1:5703, timeout: 0, bind-any: true
2014-09-05 05:47:24,650 INFO c.h.n.SocketConnector [hz._hzInstance_2_dev.cached.thread-2] [127.0.0.1]:5702 [dev] [3.2.4] Could not connect to: /127.0.0.1:5703. Reason: SocketException[Connection refused to address /127.0.0.1:5703]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hazelcast server should try to bind on the port specified in the port property.  If the default port is not available to bind on, Hazelcast should increment the port number (using the port count flag) till it gets a free port to bind on.  Unless mistaken, it may try to bind on three ports or one by default - will check and update accordingly.  You can set the port auto-increment to false if you want the Hazelcast server to simply bind on one port and not increment.

```
<port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
```

Also, make sure that port 5701 is not being used by another process and is available to bind on and that there is nothing on the system preventing a server to bind on that port such as any firewall etc.